# Preserve line breaks when reading cell content using nodeValue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I have a table cell whose value contains a line break as shown below.

```
<td>Foo
Bar</td>
```

I am reading the cell content using `td.childNodes[0].nodeValue` and passing the value in an Ajax request. But IE8 reads the LF as space such that *"Foo%20Bar"* gets sent instead of *"Foo%0ABar"*. However, in Chrome LF is preserved.

Is there an alternative way of reading the cell in IE so that LF is retained?

Comment: Don't have a "native" IE8 to test, but on an "emulated" IE8, I found that `white-space` setting somehow affects the final nodeValue. Try to apply `white-space:pre-wrap` on it before getting its nodeValue.

Comment: @nnnnnn Same problem with `td.innerHTML`

Comment: @Passerby `nodeValue` continues to give space for LF even after applying `white-space:pre-wrap` to td. But with `white-space:pre` got `%0D` (CR) in IE!!

Comment: @Somu Huh, my "standalone" IE8 gives `%0D` in both `pre-wrap` and `pre`. Anyway, since a single `%0D` is so strange, I think you are quite safe to target that and replace it to `%0A`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that You should detect if browser is IE and then apply an action (maybe replace of "%20" back to "%0A").

Comment: But that would replace legitimate spaces by line feeds